# Facebook app invite immediately deleted from notifications

Tags: facebook, notifications, invite, invitation

I have a website where we use the request dialog to allow users to invite their friends to check us out.  From the inviters side everything works as expected.  The person being invited does get the notification, but it is immediately deleted.  So they would see the red 1 over the globe for only a half a second, but it immediately dissapears and the message does not stay in their list of notifications.  They do get the invite in the apps and games section.  This used to work, but for some reason it has stopped.  Is this possibly a config thing with the app settings within facebook? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED
A little more detail on this.  I created this as a web app in facebook apps. It looks like it also needs to have the App on Facebook setting checked with values added for the canvas url.  It works as expected now.  Heres a link to what pointed me in the right direction

[Notification for facebook app requests not showing up](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8677823/notification-for-facebook-app-requests-not-showing-up)